# switch, if-else and math

Tags: java, math

This is just part of the code. So for some reason when I try to run this and the values are within  acceptable ranges i get an "Invalid weight!" response but it shouldn't being doing that as an else statement.

So... I select 1 as the selection that I want where I should enter an age in months and a weight in kg. the age has to be between 0 and 24 months. The weight has to be between 2 and 15 kg.

```
If weight(kg) >= (age(months))/3 + 2 and 
   weight(kg) <= (5*age(months))/12 + 5...
```

I want to print out "Healthy" If not withing that range - not healthy.

```
System.out.println("(1) months then weight in kg");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int selection = input.nextInt();
switch(selection){
case 1:
    System.out.println("Enter age in months: ");
    double month = input.nextDouble(); 
    if(month >= 0 && month <= 24){   
        System.out.println("Enter a weight in kg: ");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Not a baby anymore");
        System.exit(0);    
    }
    double weight = input.nextInt();
    if(weight >= 2 && weight <= 15 && weight >= (month/3) +2 && weight <= ((5 * month)/12) +5) {
        System.out.println("Healthy!");
    } else if(weight <= (month/3) +2 && weight >= ((5 * month)/12) +5) {
        System.out.println("Not Healthy!");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Invalid Weight!");
    }
    break;

...
}
```

Comment: You may not be receiving input correctly. Print out the weight variable and see if it's a real value and not some garbage. Also, you're using `input.nextInt()`, but you're setting `weight` as a `double`. Keep your datatypes consistent.

Comment: What series of inputs fails you?

Comment: The datatype was a tired error on my part. Having the or condition fixed my problem. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
} else if(weight <= (month/3) +2 && weight >= ((5 * month)/12) +5) {
```

part is wrong, since the two conditions can't be both true (for example, if `month` is 6, you get `weight <= 4 && weight >= 7.5` which is false for any `weight`), so if the condition for printing `"Healthy!"` is false, you'll always reach the `else` statement and print `"Invalid Weight!"`.

You probably want at least one of them to be true (i.e. an OR condition) :

```
} else if(weight <= (month/3) +2 || weight >= ((5 * month)/12) +5) {
```

Comment: This was my problem, thank you so much! I'm just starting with java and I'm a tired college student. I completely missed that. Having the or condition fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("(1) months then weight in kg");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int selection = input.nextInt();
        switch(selection){
            case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter age in months: ");
            double month = input.nextDouble(); 
                if(month >= 0 && month <= 24){   
                    System.out.println("Enter a weight in kg: ");
                } else{
                    System.out.println("Not a baby anymore");
                    System.exit(0);    
                }
            double weight = input.nextInt();
                if((weight >= 2) &&( weight <= 15 )&&( weight >= (month/3) +2 )&& (weight <= ((5 * month)/12) +5)) {
                    System.out.println("Healthy!");
                } else if((weight <= (month/3) +2 )&& (weight >= ((5 * month)/12) +5)) {
                    System.out.println("Not Healthy!");
                } else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Weight!");
                }
                break;

       }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
/******execution in eclipse************/
/*
(1) months then weight in kg
Enter a number: 1
Enter age in months: 
0
Enter a weight in kg: 
3
Healthy!
*/
```

Comment: always put some parentheses with logical  operators;